# Как добавить изображение в Android-приложение?

Tags: android, java

Пишу первую программку для Android (Java). Хочу сделать ImageView с картинкой из ресурсов (через imageView.setImageResource(value)). Положил картинку в res/drawable. В коде еще не использовал. При компиляции странная ошибка:

> res\drawable\fish.png: Invalid file
> name: must contain only [a-z0-9_.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте сделать в Eclipse Clean проекта и проверьте названия файлов ваших ресурсов. Подобная ошибка встречается, когда есть в названиях символы отличные от латиницы и цифр, например русские.

Comment: Похоже, глюк.

Answer (score 1):

Вы скорее всего указываете путь не верно. Должно быть так:

```
imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.fish);
```

Comment: Не, оказалось, действительно глюк. Rebuild помог. В коде я даже не написал еще эту строку (использование ресурса).

Answer (score 0):

Возможно он с большими буквами и надо сделать их в расширений png